# jQuery appendTo doesn't appear to be working

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I am attempting to output an image with an associated popout with jQuery mobile, i have the following code in a loop:

```
for( var i = 0, c = imageArray.length; i < c; i++ ) {
    counter ++;
    // Create new Image element
    var img = $('<img data-rel="popup" class="image"/>').attr({src: imageArray[i], href: "#"+"image"+counter});
    // Append new img to our photos div
    img.appendTo('.photos');

    var popoutID = "image"+counter;
    var popout = $('<div data-role="popup"></div>').attr("id", popoutID);
    popout.appendTo('.photos');
    var popoutImg = $('<img />').attr("src", imageArray[i]);
    popoutImg.appendTo(popoutID);
}
```

This output the image correctly, the popout div with the correct id, however when i attempt to append the image into the popout, the web inspector shows it as empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `appendTo` is pointing to a string, not the popout:

```
popoutImg.appendTo(popout);
```

I like to add a `$` in front of the variable as a reminder, so I know it's a jQuery object:

```
var $popout = $('<div data-role="popup"></div>').attr("id", popoutID);
$popout.appendTo('.photos');
var popoutImg = $('<img />').attr("src", imageArray[i]);
popoutImg.appendTo($popout);
```

Comment: Hi Mottie, i've amended my code as suggested and i appear to be getting the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $popout is not defined `

Comment: Scrap that, looks like my js hadn't updated fully. Its appending into the popup now. Thank you!